# Can't submit my form using anchor instead of button

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form id="activateform" method="post" action="/admin/changeStatusUser">

    <input type="text" hidden="" value="7" name="userId"></input>
    <a class="icon-5 info-tooltip" title="Activate" href="" onclick="document.getElementById('activateform').submit()"></a>

</form>
```

Here's my form that I need to submit when clicking the link(Can't use the button because the link has the style already defined). However, it's not working, on click it refreshes the page. However, if I change the anchor to input, everything works... so what am 
I doing wrong with my anchor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `href=""` attribute to `href="#"`

Answer (score 3):

As others said, change href to `#` or, another way is to add `return false;` to onclick handler:

```
<a class="icon-5 info-tooltip" title="Activate" href="" onclick="document.getElementById('activateform').submit();return false;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change href attribute to #
Ex.

```
<a class="icon-5 info-tooltip" title="Activate" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('activateform').submit()"></a>
```

or change it to javascript:
Ex.

```
<a class="icon-5 info-tooltip" title="Activate" href="javascript:" onclick="document.getElementById('activateform').submit()"></a>
```